# Website looks really bad on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have been building my first website after learning some HTML/CSS about a month ago. It looks good on all desktop browsers i've tried (safari, firefox, chrome, IE), but when i tested it on ios safari/chrome it looks really bad...

After doing a lot of searching, I can't seem to find the answer, any help on this would be most appreciated!

I have a wrapper div and some other divs set to 100% width in css

CSS

```
    html,body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}

.wrapper {
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        width:100%;
        margin:auto;
        height:9000px;;
        z-index:0;
}

#home {
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        width:100%;
        margin:auto;
        height:1000px;
        background-color:#00ADEE;
        z-index:0;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>      
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="home">
        <div id="homecontainer">
        <div id="homelogo"></div>
                <a href="#thumbnailgallery" class="smoothScroll"><div id="projectbutton"></div></a>
                <a href="#about" class="smoothScroll"><div id="aboutbutton"></div></a>
                <a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll"><div id="contactbutton"></div></a>
        </div>
    </div> <!--Home closing tag-->
```

Is there some sort of HTML code i'm missing to detect a mobile display?

Comment: Is this your full HTML? You're missing some elements, like your HTML tag, and some closing divs. Let me know if that is your full code or not. Also, you won't need to give the wrapper margin:auto if it's 100%. You'll want to give it something like a width of 90%, and then give it margin:auto. That will center it, and make it look decent on mobile. You'll need to make sure that when you ask a question you have provided us with as many details as possible, and the full code that you are using. Your question will get down voted like you see happening already.

Comment: You need to use CSS media queries

Comment: CSS media queries, also you can use .htaccess

Comment: Can you provide the link to your website?

Comment: post some screenshot of what you experience and what do you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of viewport meta to define the initial scale on a mobile device

so add the viewport meta in head tag like the following example

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>      
        <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="home">
        <div id="homecontainer">
        <div id="homelogo"></div>
                <a href="#thumbnailgallery" class="smoothScroll"><div id="projectbutton"></div></a>
                <a href="#about" class="smoothScroll"><div id="aboutbutton"></div></a>
                <a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll"><div id="contactbutton"></div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

read more on viewport meta here http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972